# How to rotate an object around its corner

Tags: d3.js, svg, rotation

i'm trying to figure out what's the default anchorpoint for d3 rotation while i intend to rotate a line around its end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: A simple bar chart</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* No style rules here yet */       
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 400;
            var h = 200;


            var dataset = [ 1,2,3,4];

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", 50)
               .attr("y", 50 )
               .attr("width", 100)
               .attr("height",1)
               .attr("transform", (d, i)=>" rotate("+10*i+")")
              ;



        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the lines are a space apart from each other. what kind of translation is also need to make them touch eachother at one end? and what's the center of rotation used by d3 defaults?

thanks.

Comment: I wrote an answer but I just deleted it (users with >10k can see it), because I found the dupe. Also, here is a fiddle with the correct code for you: https://jsfiddle.net/zf9jsyj6/ It is basically the code in my deleted answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I’ll proceed to close the question

Comment: You don't need to delete it. That's what "duplicates" are for.